# XSLT Select the last node with a given value

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

this is my first message, i have the follow XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<searchResponse>
   <Devices>
      <Device>
         <DeviceId>222</DeviceId>
         <DeviceNickName>Phone</DeviceNickName>
         <DeviceTypeCode>01</DeviceTypeCode>
         <MappingStatusHistorys>
            <MappingStatusHistory>
               <Status>A</Status>
               <StatusDescription>AMS Managed</StatusDescription>
               <Date>2015-06-25T06:00:46-05:00</Date>
            </MappingStatusHistory>
            <MappingStatusHistory>
               <Status>SI</Status>
               <StatusDescription>Suspended By Issuer</StatusDescription>
               <Date>2015-06-25T06:00:15-05:00</Date>
            </MappingStatusHistory>
            <MappingStatusHistory>
               <Status>A</Status>
               <StatusDescription>AMS Managed</StatusDescription>
               <Date>2015-06-25T05:52:21-05:00</Date>
            </MappingStatusHistory>
         </MappingStatusHistorys>
         <StatusHistorys />
         <ProvisionPath>Yellow</ProvisionPath>
      </Device>
   </Devices>
   <Response>
      <ResponseCode>00</ResponseCode>
      <Description>SUCCESS</Description>
   </Response>
</searchResponse>
```

I want to get `<MappingStatusHistory> -> <Status>` and `<Date>` of the last node with `<Status> ="A"` i really think that it is not possible with and XSLT, someone experts with any idea.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "last"? Is it last in document order, or last in chronological order?

Comment: For me the last A node: `<MappingStatusHistory>
               <Status>A</Status>
               <StatusDescription>AMS Managed</StatusDescription>
               <Date>2015-06-25T05:52:21-05:00</Date>
            </MappingStatusHistory>`

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have provided, you can try out the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp" select="//MappingStatusHistory[Status='A']"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$temp[last()]/Status"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$temp[last()]/Date"/>
```

Comment: If the answer is correct then please accept the answer